# Can I buy PSN games and DLC without giving Sony my credit card info?

Tags: psn

In light of the recent security problems at Sony, I'm very hesitant of giving PSN my credit card info.

Is it possible to buy games, DLC, etc. without giving my credit card to PSN?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes. You can buy a PlayStation Network Card at a retailer; these prepaid cards can be used in the PSN Store instead of credit cards. (The value of PSN cards is listed in your local currency, so it's easy to tell how much you're spending and how much games cost. As an example, here are [$50 cards for sale](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=playstation+network+card&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=10769073477045175223&sa=X&ei=v_7qTezFLIjpgAesuMDXCQ&ved=0CGYQ8wIwAw).)

Answer (score 0):

You can purchase [PlayStation Network Cards](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/explore/playstationnetwork/psn-cards/) from your local game retailer. They work just like gift cards. If you spent $10 on one, it will give you $10 on the PlayStation Store.

You can also buy cards for PlayStation Plus, if you want to upgrade your account, but do not wish to use a credit card.

[image: Pre-paid PlayStation Cards]